# Are there any clear differences between the contributions of an AI bot and a human being to fora like Stack Exchange?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language, artificial-intelligence, cognitive-sciences, philosophy-of-computer-science

I perform the same tasks an AI Bot does when answering questions here: I go online and make sure that my answer can be validated online as a self-check. Is there a practical difference between me and a current AI engine with regards to my activity as a Stack Exchange member? How philosophically is there a distinction in those two types of language contributions?

Comment: There are already bots on the stock exchange, so why not the stack exchange? They're identifying cancer, flying planes and driving trucks. Philosophy can't be that hard.

Comment: @ScottRowe Not just Philosophy. There are Physics, Chemistry SE sites as well. From a functional perspective, my activity on the SE network is no different than a Bot

Comment: @ScottRowe What kind of member screening (if any) would be required to "fix" this problem. If this really can be considered a problem. Do these Bots mark the beginning of the end for sites like the Stack Exchange?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is more of a 'meta' site question, but I'll go along. So, in the other areas I mentioned, no one seems to mind the improvements. We'd all like less cancer, safer plane journeys and so on. The question is, who would mind if AI started to answer questions here? Assuming it did that better than people do, we would have better answers, and maybe even better questions. The issue would be that people *enjoy* participating here. So, like any other club, they could keep non-persons out somehow. Who would be inflicting AI on Stack Exchange if no one wanted that?

Comment: Actually, this is the other side of a huge problem with computer systems: how to identify a person. We would like it if nobody could steal our stuff online. If there was an absolute way to identify each person, that problem would go away. Now we want to also absolutely know if something was *not* a person. Presumably, they just wouldn't be in the database of known persons. Done.

Comment: I did ask some philosophical questions to ChatGPT. The answer looked coherent on the surface, but the logic was wrong in the end - just the logic steps.

Comment: Let's experiment - take some questions from here, try them in ChatGPT, and see if you like the answers.

Comment: But here is a difference: when we post a question, we get many different answers from people with wildly different backgrounds and points of view. The bot would just give you 1 answer.

Comment: @Frank Do you believe an algorithm can be written to expose the errors in logic or behavior that you have seen?

Comment: @Frank Great idea to compare and contrast identical philosophical questions posed to both the Philosophy SE and ChatGPT

Comment: @ScottRowe Anonymity has been part of the internet since its inception. It's not so easy to determine "real" IP addresses from "fakes"

Comment: @StevanV.Saban Not sure. But it's probably some ways off. ChatGPT really underwhelms when precision or reliability is needed, and precision would be needed to carry out a serious logical proof, IMHO.

Comment: This seems definitely a Meta question, and many related questions already exist in Meta sites.

Comment: @Frank so, AI answers would be a lot like human answers, with errrors and so on. Should fit right in. Stevan: anonymity can still include knowing that a participant is a unique, actual person and no one / no thing is spoofing. Without that, we might as well quit.

Comment: I've revised the question to explore the basic philosophical distinction between AI and human language production.

Comment: @JD Thank you!!! You managed to get to the heart of the matter.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban No sweat. It's an increasingly important question, and one that many people struggle to ask and answer. Thanks for bringing your curiosity to the table.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no difference. All living beings are made up of inanimate particles (electrons, quarks) and so are the non-living beings. You are asking because the universe has evolved to the state where you are asking. You don't have any free-will. We are sort of "programmed" by the universe. This implies that the AI bot certainly doesn't have free-will (which is programmed by us; we are sort of "programmed" by the universe). In fact, we are just "puppets" controlled by the laws of physics.

Answer (score 1):

> I perform the same tasks an AI Bot does when answering questions here: I go online and make sure that my answer can be validated online as a self-check.

Current AI technology may produce language, but it does not do it like the human brain and the very question of 'validation' is what distinguishes people from such technology. AI researchers for decades dreamed of having a system that thinks like people (see [GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Problem_Solver)), and one such formulation of the problem is the [physical symbol system hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_symbol_system) and it's closely allied argument of the existence of the [LoT or language of thought (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/language-thought/). But all attempts to create working software along these lines has led to the [framing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_problem), and the second generation of cognitive scientists has led to counter arguments against the standard cognitive science model such as [connectionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionism) and [embodied cognition (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/embodied-cognition/).

Currently, OpenAI's success with it's current version of ChatGPT [LLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model) (and others like Google's Bard based on LaMDA) has people again wrestling with knowledge about narrow AI and questions about [AGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence) as a hypothesis with persons such as Altman and Goetzel (and other futurists) stoking public hopes and fears that machine systems are about to rise up as sentient beings or that the [singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity) is about to occur. Happily or sadly, depending on your view, AGI is nowhere near coming to fruition and people still struggle with fundamental critical thinking skills, such as [Blake Lamoine](https://wikibiostars.in/technology/blake-lemoine/), who makes claims that hold no philosophical water.

> Is there a practical difference between me and a current AI engine with regards to my activity as a Stack Exchange member.

Yes, there is very much a practical difference. You are a person, not a LLM, and your contributions therefore are not marked by [semantic hallucinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence)). When you contribute your language skills exhibit common sense, where as an LLM's do not. One way to think about this is that you can be distinguished from an LLM with the use of the [Turing Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) precisely because you are capable of [common sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_sense) or exhibit other language usage indicative of psychological regularities such as [cognitive biases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias). And a philosopher of mind has an additional tool box that a talented clinical psychologist may not, a vocabulary to describe and understand how minds work [metaphysically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics). While some people are skeptical contemporary philosophy has any value, in fact, contemporary philosophy is more sophisticated than it has ever been as more and more philosophies-of come to maturity.

Comment: It's very analogous to language translation apps. Google translate has become effective enough to for me to send emails in German without the receiver really knowing if I can speak German or not. I believe the big "language" issues of AI will come from language translation algorithms

Comment: It's the ability to mimic behavior that is concerning. It's ability to be anonymous. These are tools that can be used for sinister behavior without the Bot passing a Turing test

Comment: It is concerning, because like nuclear energy, there are potential abuses that arise. People struggle to be rational, and giving one group of people a tool that creates the appearance of human beings where human beings exist not blurs the decision making process epistemologically for people who distinguish between reason and testimony when making choices. People will do for other people what they will not do which appears unreasonable otherwise. When computers can stand in for people, then what constitutes as testimony becomes dangerous when the motivations of tool users are questionable.

Comment: Indeed. In fact the differences are still quite large in my experience. I spent several hours with ChatGPT asking it questions about logic and it produced a load of self-contradictory nonsense. It was like talking to someone who is insane: it literally could not hold a coherent thought from one minute to the next.

Comment: @Bumble Given your perspicuity, I'd expect it. The logic of transforming symbols by semantic grounding you've internalized is fundamentally different that the statistical methods of token prediction which is, even with billions of data points, a shallow syntax processing. You, kind sir, are a living validation that meaning in natural language demonstrates semantic internalism. 'Meaning' is a universal which is more than mere utternace construction. It is a computation that draws from learning from the limbic to the neocortex; it is an exciting time that AI systems will continue to grow.

Answer (score 0):

I lt looks like **we** are **unable** to distinguish ...

[image]

from

Mount Everest

Answer (score 0):

I put a cryptic crossword clue to ChatGPT. Not only did the gormless bot suggest an incorrect answer, the answer suggested had seven letters instead of the six I had specified in my question, an oversight that ChatGPT was quick to acknowledge when I raised it. Perhaps if I upgrade to the paid version it will be better at figuring out how many letters are contained in a word. In the meantime, I will not be relying upon it for philosophical insights.

So the answer to your question is yes, there is a key difference. ChatGPT immediately recognises its mistakes when they are pointed out to it, whereas humans on stackexchange will stubbornly defend their delusions.